# Tensorflow rnn: name 'seq2seq' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, attributeerror, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying this notebook:
https://github.com/sjchoi86/Tensorflow-101/blob/master/notebooks/char_rnn_sample_tutorial.ipynb

I have a problem with this line In[6]:

```
outputs, final_state = seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, istate, cell, loop_function=None, scope='rnnlm')
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'seq2seq' is not defined
```

I am using tensorflow 1.0.1. I tried

```
tf.contrib.seq2seq
```

but I am getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rnn_decoder'
```

I think it is a probleme with the new implementation of rnn network in tensorflow 1.0.1 but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `seq2seq` has been moved to [tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/rnn_decoder). You should change this line to:

```
outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, istate, cell, loop_function=None, scope='rnnlm')
```

Comment: Now, I have another error for this line:
    output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs),[-1, rnn_size] )
the error message:  TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.

Comment: @Aggounix Starting tf 0.12, `tf.concat` has changed the order of parameters it takes. I think `output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(outputs, 1),[-1, rnn_size] )` should work?

Comment: @Aggounix I think they changed it to make it consistent with `numpy.concatenate((arr1, arr2, ...), axis)`